# Why does width and height CSS not affect this button element?

Tags: html, css

If I have

```
<button></button>
```

with

```
button {width: 1ex; height: 1ex;}
```

It renders like this in Firefox (47.0)

[image]

```css
button {
  width: 1ex;
  height: 1ex;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Why isn't it square?

Comment: it's the same in chrome, it is because of default padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox applies a default padding to the element as shown in the screenshot below (`6px` on the left and on the right)

Also if you need to get a perfect squared button you need to set (or remove) its border, e.g.

```
button { 
  width: 1ex;
  height: 1ex;
  padding: 0; 
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
}
```

(then you should probably adjust the width and height, because the button size decreases a lot)

---

Computed box model on Firefox:

[image]

Comment: it seems it's not a square also on Chrome (16x15)

Comment: The box model diagram nicely shows *how* Firefox arrived at the final size, but not *why*. Why is it 0x12 in the centre part and not NxN?

Comment: @spraff that's just a glitch in the Chrome box model inspector. Because there's no content in the `<button></button>` it thinks has a zero width. The Firefox box model inspector does actually show the button as having a non-zero width

Answer (score 0):

What version of Firefox are you using? I can't replicate your problem, which makes me think it's either your browser or something else in your CSS. This snippet

```css
body {
  background: #000
}
button {
  width: 1ex;
  height: 1ex;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

looks like this for me in Chrome [image: Chrome screenshot]…… and like this [image: Firefox screenshot] for me in Firefox (I promise these are two different screenshots in the two different browsers!). And, for me, changing the width and height to 10ex does make the button a larger square, in both browsers.

Comment: When I Run that, it presents as about 3:1 aspect ratio.

Comment: Weird. What version of FF? What does it look like for you in other browsers?

Comment: Version 47 on Ubuntu